Easy 2d custom shader for Unity 3d: charts, flat/ortho mesh, etc
I just need to draw a flat mesh (say a 2d graph) on top of everything. What could be easier? create an object, adding it a mesh precalculated in homogenous (-1,+1) coordinates to match SV_POSITION output of vertex shader, draw it last - and that is all.
Big win is: no UI Canvas, no MatrixMVP calculations per vertex per frame, no camera switching to ortho and back - you are in control of everything, you can even re-use vertex.z position to pass a color.
And the shader looks easy:
float4 vert (float4 vertex: POSITION) : SV_POSITION
{return vertex;}
fixed4 frag(): SV_Target
{return fixed4(1,1,1,1);}

What is spoiling the fun: Unity is no longer twicks your mesh to look upside up: say on Metal or DirectX, or in the Landscape Left mode of an Android phone, etc. Usually Unity does this magic inside of the VP matrix. I know it, because if I add the mul(unity_MatrixVP), then it always upside up. The image attached demonstrated that the red mesh is oriented ok (going through  the VP matrix) and the white is ... depends on the platform, screen orientation, and may be other factors.
Anyone has an advice on how to extract from the VP matrix the parts responsible for mesh correct orientation. I tried many combinations comoaring GL.GetGPUProjectionMatrix and Matrix4x4.Ortho, but could not get it to work.



What did you mean by "twicks" & "comoaring"?

Without the source for Unity3D's implementation per platform, you are limited to deducing and recreating the operations performed. IMO, the UI route seems easier.
